# Powershell + Signing Issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have two PS scripts, one is on a local machine while the other is on the remote machine. The local machine is performing the following operations

1. Copying files from the local machine to the remote machine
2. Asking the remote script to sign the files that are copied to the remote machine (the remote machine and the remote script are located on the same machine_
3. After the files have been signed , copies the signed files back to the source folder

However I am facing an issue here . the issue is as soon as the remote server tries to sign the files it gives me a message

> no provider is specified for the store or the object

I believe this is not a powershell error and is somehow related to access issues,but i really cant figure it out on my own.

The remote server is managed by the release engineering team and I would not like to make any changes there.

Please suggest

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think signing certificate would have been installed by release engineering team member. So when you are trying invoke script with your credential it fails. You can ask one of your release engineering team member to run the script from your machine with his credentials. If it succeeds for them then it is because of signing certificate is not installed for your account. (Normally release engineering team would not prefer to provide access to other due to security and safety reasons)